# assign ondrop to an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm still struggeling with an piece of JavaScript coding. I've stripped it down to the following coding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>dad-test</title>
<body>
<div  id='spaltemu'> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function allowdrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
function drag(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
}
function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
    var spkart = document.getElementById ('spaltemu');
    spkart.ondrop = 'drop(event)';
    spkart.ondragover = 'allowdrop(event)';
    alert ('Halt');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When running this code the debugger shows that neither the assignment of ondrop nor the one of ondragover works. Debugger shows "null" as value. I don't understand what's wrong. Any hint is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to this though I don't understand the problem completely. Why does this lead to an error:
...

```
function allowdrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
var spkart = document.getElementById ('spaltemu');
spkart.ondragover = 'allowdrop(event)';
```

while thisone works:

```
spkart.ondragover = function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
};
```

Nevertheless I found a solution ...